# Drag a view programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-animation, android-view

I'm writing playing cards game. I have implemented dragging and dropping one view onto another based on [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/) tutorial.

Now I want to animate opponent moves.

Is there easy way to to this?

I thought about using `TouchUtils.dragViewBy(...)`, but it isn't supported on device.

Comment: "but it isn't supported on device"... what device?

Comment: I mean that using android test classes is probably not allowed in apps because it gives `NoClassFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

for opponents move, shouldn't you use animations instead?

for this, you could use either the [**old API**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) or the [**new one**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html), or use a [**compatibility library**](http://nineoldandroids.com/) instead .

do note that if you run animations on old android versions (even with the compatibility library) meaning API 10 and below, the view only looks to be on the position that you see it, but actually it stayed on the original position.